# VBA escaping characters in formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have a formula which hardcoded should look like this:

```
=SUMMEWENNS(Rawdata!K2:K3446;Rawdata!I2:I3446;"bezahlt";Rawdata!A2:A3446;">="&DATWERT("18.03.2013 00:00");Rawdata!A2:A3446;"<="&DATWERT("24.03.2013 23:59"))
```

I want to add the formula via VBA into different cells and have come up with this string, but there is a syntax problem and I cannot find the error. It most likely has to do with the escaping of the characters espacially with the "DATWERT".

```
qq = Chr(34)
Cells(5, fieldextsales).FormulaLocal = "=SUMMEWENNS(RawData!K2:K" & _
                     maxnumrows & ";Rawdata!I2:I" & maxnumrows & ";" & qq & _
                     "bezahlt" & qq & ";Rawdata!A2:A" & maxnumrows & ";" & _
                     qq & ">= " & DATWERT(weekstart & " 00:00") * 1 & qq & _
                     ";RawData!A2:A" & maxnumrows & ";" & qq & "<= " & _
                     DATWERT(weekend & " 23:59") * 1 & qq & ")"
```

Could anybody help me out? Hope I get the hang of it then.

Thx

Comment: You could start by putting the content in a string and print it to check that it looks like what you expected.

Comment: thx for the advice. it still stops at the DATWERT. Thinks its a function which is not declared?

Answer (score 2):

Here we go:

```
"=SUMMEWENNS(RawData!K2:K" & _
maxnumrows & ";Rawdata!I2:I" & maxnumrows & ";" & _
"""bezahlt""" & ";Rawdata!A2:A" & maxnumrows & ";" & _
""">=""&DATWERT(""" & weekstart & " 00:00"")" & _
";RawData!A2:A" & maxnumrows & ";" & _
"""<=""&DATWERT(""" & weekend & " 23:59""))"
```

Answer (score 1):

From the **VBA** side you use plain English function names, not local names => DATWERT shoud be DateValue, unless you want to embed it into your formula.